# Amazon AWSS3TransferManager fails in ios to upload multipart data

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, awss3transfermanager

I am trying to upload a NSData object (which can be either an image or a video) to Amazon S3.

Everything works good when the file size is lower than 5Mb. When it is bigger, the AWS SDK is switching to multipart upload and then it fails with:

*Anonymous users cannot initiate multipart uploads.  Please authenticate.*

I am using the latest AWSS3 SDK version currently available (2.5.5).

```
- (void) uploadDataToAWS: (NSData *) mediaData
             contentType: (NSString *) contentType
                  bucket: (NSString *) bucket
                  region: (NSString *) region
               objectKey: (NSString *) objectKey
             accessKeyId: (NSString *) accessKeyId
         secretAccessKey: (NSString *) secretAccessKey
            sessionToken: (NSString *) sessionToken
         progressHandler: (void (^) (int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend)) progressHandler
   withCompletionHandler: (void (^) (BOOL success)) completionHandler {

    OwnAWSCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [OwnAWSCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:accessKeyId secretKey:secretAccessKey sessionKey:sessionToken];
    AWSServiceConfiguration *awsServiceConfiguration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                                                   credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = awsServiceConfiguration;

    //Since S3 does not support objects uploads (only files), will write first locally:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.forUpload", [self randomStringWithLength:10]]];
    [mediaData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    //Configure upload request
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.bucket = bucket;
    uploadRequest.key = objectKey;
    uploadRequest.body =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    uploadRequest.contentType = contentType;

    uploadRequest.uploadProgress =  ^(int64_t bytesSent, int64_t totalBytesSent, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToSend){
        progressHandler (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend);
    };

    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

    [[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        //Remove the generated file
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];

        if (task.error != nil) {
            if( task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled
               && task.error.code != AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused) {
                NSLog(@"(%i) %@", (int)task.error.code, [task.error localizedDescription]);
                NSLog(@"Message: %@", task.error.userInfo[@"Message"]);
            }
            completionHandler (NO);
        } else {
            completionHandler(YES);
        }
        return task;
    }];
}
```

OwnAWSCredentialsProvider.m:

```
#import "OwnAWSCredentialsProvider.h"

@implementation OwnAWSCredentialsProvider

+ (instancetype)credentialsWithAccessKey:(NSString *)accessKey
                               secretKey:(NSString *)secretKey
                              sessionKey:(NSString*)sessionKey
{
    OwnAWSCredentialsProvider *credentials = [[OwnAWSCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:accessKey secretKey:secretKey sessionKey:sessionKey];
    return credentials;
}

- (instancetype)initWithAccessKey:(NSString *)accessKey
                        secretKey:(NSString *)secretKey
                       sessionKey:(NSString*)sessionKey
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _accessKey = accessKey;
        _secretKey = secretKey;
        _sessionKey = sessionKey;
    }
    return self;
}

- (AWSTask<AWSCredentials *> *)credentials {
    return [[AWSTask taskWithResult:nil] continueWithBlock:^id _Nullable(AWSTask * _Nonnull task) {
        return task;
    }];
}

- (void)invalidateCachedTemporaryCredentials {  
}

@end
```

Credentials are generated on each upload and they are valid and working great on files smaller than 5Mb.

I don't use pre-signed URLs, so I need to make this piece of code to work somehow.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, I have finally found where was the problem:

I used OwnAWSCredentialsProvider, as a wrapper of AWSCredentialsProvider.

Here, the getter for credentials was always returning nil (not sure why it worked for small files).

Instead, I am using now AWSBasicSessionCredentialsProvider, provided by the AWS SDK and everything works good.

```
AWSBasicSessionCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSBasicSessionCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithAccessKey:accessKeyId secretKey:secretAccessKey sessionToken:sessionToken];
```

Comment: What is "sessionToken" in this method?

Comment: I am getting accessKeyId, secretAccessKey and sessionToken from my server, which is requesting this from AWS. Then I use them in my upload method.